# push next view with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: cocoa-touch, didselectrowatindexpath

I added this method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to go to the next view 
no errors but i can't go to the next view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    detailhadith *detaihd = [[detailhadith alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailhadith" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detaihd animated:YES];
    [detaihd release];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can just add a subview like this: `[self.view addSubview:nextView.view];` if you don't have a navigationController.